# JavaScript Array Fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a question regarding the next code, how can I fill the 'events' array dynamically, with a for / while ? ( I can't fill it manually due to the fact that there are a lot of datas )
Thank you

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek'
        },
        defaultDate: '2014-12-15',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Test',
                start: '2014-12-17'
            }
        ]
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: You simply define it before you call the `.fullCalendar` function and then use it's variable name in the function.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? How is the data created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array variable and then use it when you initialize the calendar like so:

```
var events = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    events.push({title: 'Test' + i, start: '2014-12-17'});
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-12-15',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: events
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (immediately-invoked function expression)

```
events: (function () {

    var events = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i +=1) {

        // You can do here anything.

        events.push({
            title: 'Test' + i,
            start: '2014-12-17'
        });
    }

    return events;

})()
```